# UTM Not Working

Tags: url, analytics, utm

We are currently using a number of UTM codes with various companies to track a campaigns to our website. While most of them have worked without issue, three have failed to be recorded by Google Analytics and they all use the same format (two of the URLs are below). Any idea why this would be? The links themselves work, it's just GA hasn't accepted them at all.

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__www.semble.co.nz_mobilepay_bnz_-3Futm-5Fsource-3Dbnz-5Fapp-26utm-5Fmedium-3Donline-5Fbanner-26utm-5Fcontent-3Durl-5Fappnotification-26utm-5Fcampaign-3Dmobilepay-5Fcampaign&d=CwMFAg&c=N-xPqDyeLJg5V3gLll2thA&r=lbXMFujwGwA66Ivf0fYOaY8Dv5vHXIMr8z9PppNbh6c&m=JP3JnHYmkJ3J1YBwv9iHgnMsJJZdyrflVUuPxw_okaA&s=xT3UnMPmiP-DJPNwtQhywHsRWvmMg7PMylFMQjrGov4&e=

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=http-3A__www.semble.co.nz_mobilepay_bnz_-3Futm-5Fsource-3Dbnz-5Fapp-26utm-5Fmedium-3Dgoogle-26utm-5Fcontent-3Durl-5Fappnotification-26utm-5Fcampaign-3Dmobilepay-5Fcampaign&d=CwMFAg&c=N-xPqDyeLJg5V3gLll2thA&r=lbXMFujwGwA66Ivf0fYOaY8Dv5vHXIMr8z9PppNbh6c&m=JP3JnHYmkJ3J1YBwv9iHgnMsJJZdyrflVUuPxw_okaA&s=wN-S93ZKKnjHZoGSPZJCTTvDk9NeqUd7zG9W5MoGwKA&e=

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You URL is not correctly builded, you must found any of this strings on your URL :

```
&utm-campaign=
&utm-source=
&utm-medium=
```

And didn't appear, seems like your system are recoding URL in some point.